# How do I make PHP understand that DOCUMENT_ROOT is not a string?

Tags: php, constants

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DOCUMENT_ROOT - assumed 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' in /home/syole/public_html/includes/config.php on line 21

Notice: Use of undefined constant DOCUMENT_ROOT - assumed 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' in /home/syole/public_html/includes/config.php on line 22
```

The PHP has seen an undefined constant which it is treating as the string, which has cause my website to display only a blank page, how do I make php understand that DOCUMENT_ROOT is predefined / should be predefined and is not a string?

I don't know where a " server configuration " might be but my website used to work and now it doesn't so I assume it must be defined correctly there, wherever that is, most likely on cpanel?

I think Coda2 caused this problem whilst connecting to my mySQL database.

I just cant seem to fix this issue and prior to adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, I didn't even know of this error.

Comment: It's not a constant. It's not pre-defined. You need to quote it when accessing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this:

```
$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]
```

Do this instead:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

You need to quote strings (which this is), but not constants (which this isn't).

If you're using it inside an interpolated string, do it like this:

```
$a = "foo {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} bar";
```

The `{}` braces allow you to use single/double quotes inside the double quoted string.

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed this error. My website is still blank, which means my true error is something else, but this has really helped.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your config file

```
 define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

if you want to stick with your current constant call. Or you should do what @cal recommended.

Answer (score 0):

XDebug indicates that `'DOCUMENT_ROOT'` is a string, inside the Array() `$_SERVER`.

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'<br />';

echo gettype($_SERVER).'<br />';
echo gettype($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'<br />';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
echo '<pre>';
```